# Exportar tabela do DB em formato csv com colunas separadas por ponto e vírgula

Tags: php, mysql

Já consigo exportar em `CSV`, mas as colunas estão vindo separadas por `vírgula`, como fazer para virem separadas por `ponto e vírgula`?

> Meu código:

```
<?php  
      //export.php  
 if(isset($_POST["export"]))  
 {  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "simrede");  
      header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');  
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Cadastro_Alunos-Simrede.csv');  
      $output = fopen("php://output", "w");  
      fputcsv($output, array('lastname', 'firstname', 'department', 'institution', 'username',  'email', 'city', 'course1', 'password'),';');  
      $query = "SELECT * from cs_alunos ORDER BY institution";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
      {
           fputcsv($output, $row);  
      }  
      fclose($output);  
 }  
 ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguindo a própria [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fputcsv.php), basta adicinar a flag `string $delimiter = ","` alterando para ";"

```
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($out, array('this','is some', 'csv "stuff", you know.'),';');
fclose($out);
```

Comment: Obrigado @IsraelZebulon ! Bem simples, vou dar uma lida na documentação.

Comment: não funcionou adequadamente, apenas o cabeçalho vem com ponto e vírgula

Comment: tem de adicionar em while também pra fucionar